# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'

Tags: angular, typescript

[image: ****texto em negrito**ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'**]

Esse erro acontece quando é realizada uma chamada de um evento `onblur()` no componente.ts: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Procedimento do erro:

Ao realizar um cadastro, inserindo dados no primeiro campo *CÓDIGO*, com apenas 1 dígito, ele acessa um evento `OnBlur()`, que verifica se esse mesmo código digitado é maior que 0, com a expressão no Ts: **`resultado.total > 0`**, caso sendo, apresenta uma mensagem dizendo que o código já existe e se deseja alterar. Neste momento apresenta o erro no console. Alguém poderia me dizer como consertar este erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O template do componente se encontra desse jeito:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor poste o codigo inves de imagens

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: cara nao seria mais facil vc por um (charge)="funcao" seria melhor e seu input ia ficar mais limpo

Comment: cara coloca um change... e uma liberação de true ou false pra condição que deseja... trava o button... e pronto nada mto dificil n.. (change)="funcao($event.target)"

Comment: Valeu Willian, vou tentar fazer essa mudança e informo depois o feedback. Obrigado!